# Change MVC5 scaffolding to bootstrap table instead of data list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I scaffold an entity in MVC5 it outputs all the properties and labels as a datalist

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.value1)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.value1)
        </dd>
              ... etc
</dl>
```

This is a great feature but I would rather it output to a bootstrap table or a bootstrap grid.

Is there anyway to make it do that?

Comment: Most probably you will have to leverage bootstrap classes on your existing HTML tags. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

`Visual Studio` stores the scaffolding templates in the following folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView`

You can find the one you're interested in (probably `Details.cs.t4`) and edit it to suit your needs.

Hope it helps

Comment: Cool! I didn't know we could change the scaffolding templates.. Thanks :)

Comment: Ahh that's perfect.  Thanks!